# HTTP video response parsing

Tags: java, http, video, request, response

I am doing a simple HTTP GET request and the response is a video. Since video is too big I cant directly read the data. Is there a work around to know how can I confirm that the content is available. Currently I am only checking for HTTP 200 OK status, I also want to read the content whatever it might be??

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that you need to stream video over TCP?
2. If you are sure, look at MJPEG, it is simply sequence of jpeg images with headers, that you can send over http.
3. Also you can implement your own frame based video streaming protocol

Comment: Yes. I am sure that I need to stream the video. The recorder which will provide the video is providing the whole content in one go instead of segments. That content being huge is an issue.

How to proceed with 2 and 3 any links you can provide will be helpful.

Comment: 1. Why over TCP? why not UDP?
2. You need to write your own video server, that can read your input video and then convert it to popular format, and stream it.